# SharePoint calculated column based on other 2 columns

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I am struggling writing the formula for SharePoint calculated column.

I have 3 SharePoint Columns:

```
[Vaccination date];
[Infected] - Yes/No choice;
[No testing is not needed (date)]
```

In column `[No testing is not needed (date)]` I would like to calculate the date a person does not need to get tested, which means I would like to add 14 days to the `[Vaccination date]` if the person was infected.

I have been using the following formula:

```
=IF([Infected]="Yes"; [Vaccination date] + 14; "")
```

This formula seems to work only when both columns are not blank. If one of the columns is not, then I get the default date `"1900-01-13"`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK([Infected]); ISBLANK([Vaccination date])); ""; IF([Infected] = "Yes"; [Vaccination date] + 14; ""))
```

**Documentation**:

[Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v=office.14))

Comment: Thank you, worked perfectly!

Comment: Hi @ekoz, Can you please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.